# Is an 83b election ONLY applicable to equity in exchange for services?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, 83b-election

From what I can find online, it seems like IRC §83 relates to transfers of restricted equity in exchange for services provided. Is this the only applicable case for for an 83b election, or can a founder who contributes capital to a startup in exchange for a restricted ownership interest make this election (even if the restricted ownership interest is not in exchange for services provided)?

Could not find an answer in any other topics here, so please forgive me and link if available.

Comment: I'm no expert - but why would an investor be taxed on the _purchase_ of an ownership interest? That section seems to apply to the use of restricted stock as _compensation_ which could be taxable.

Comment: Founders can make an 83b election. I’ve done so.

Comment: @Rocky securities in lieu of cash dividend?

Comment: The 83b election just means you elect to be taxed based on the purchase price at the time the shares were issued.Whether you paid cash or were given the shares in exchange for a dividend the purchase price is the purchase price and it must be included in your election letter to the IRS. You also have to pay income tax on the shares the year they were issued. The benefit is capital gains rates when you sell.